Auto suggestion for deprecated HTML attributes in VS Code?
I am currently working on a template for email letters. And it's a bit annoying to type attributes such as <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> and some more often used like <td height="20" width="600"> manually. Did anyone find a way how to turn this on?
I tried to use settings like
"[html]": {
     "editor.suggest.showDeprecated": true,
     "editor.showDeprecated": true   
},

but they don't help with this. Also I didn't find any extentions which can add this possibility.

Just write your own custom Emmet snippets.
